# UIButton: Image stretched when clicking

Tags: objective-c, image, uibutton, imageview

I am using EGOImageButton to handle the asynchronous download of image. I've set the contentMode to Aspect Fit using uibutton.imageView.contentMode rather than uibutton.contentMode because it doesn't work on iPhone so I used the former. The image inside the button stretched to the size of the button when I clicked on it. What is the solution to prevent it from stretched?

Pleaase help